# Where do we use 'to'?

Tags: prepositions, to-infinitive

I always get confused using the 'to' after a verb.

For example:

I want to go there vs I want ice-cream.

I need to do calculation vs I need calculating all this.

She loves dogs vs She loves to wear fancy dresses.

Is there any specific rule when we use 'to' after a verb or when not?

Comment: It's not a matter of *when we use 'to' **after** a verb*. It's about *when do we include [**the infinitive marker**] 'to' **before** a verb?* We ***do*** include it in most cases *(I want **to watch**, He had **to go**, You need **to sleep**)*. But not in others *(I must **stop**, He let **go**, You can **wait**)*. All those highlighted verbs are infinitives, regardless of whether the explicit "marker" ***to*** is present or not.

Comment: In which context, note that *You need **sleep*** is a ***noun*** usage, same as *You need **food***. And *You need eat* simply isn't valid English - it has to be *You need **to** eat*.

Answer (score 1):

The *to* in your examples is attached to the *following* verb (I want **to go**, I need **to do**), forming an infinitive. The examples without *to* have nouns follow the main verb (I **want ice cream**, she **loves dogs**), and nouns do not have an infinitive form.

You also wouldn't use *to* if a gerund follows, eg.

> She **likes wearing** fancy dresses.

This is similar to your second example, with the caveat that *need* + gerund sounds very unnatural.

Comment: Does it mean 'Verb + noun' and 'verb + -ing(gerund)'  are same pattern?

Comment: @GKS pretty much, yes. A gerund generally acts as a noun grammatically (with some caveats, such as being able to take an object like in the example).